# How to handle the exception: "No suitable driver" while running spark-submit

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I am trying to run a spark code which will read a table on postgres database and insert it into Hive table on HDFS. To do that I have set my connection properties in a properties file as below:

```
devUserName=usrname
devPassword=pwd
gpDriverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
gpDevUrl=jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/dbname?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

And reading the properties file as:

```
  val conFile       = "testconnection.properties"
  val properties    = new Properties()
  properties.load(new FileInputStream(conFile))

  // GP Properties
  val connectionUrl = properties.getProperty("gpDevUrl")
  val devUserName   = properties.getProperty("devUserName")
  val devPassword   = properties.getProperty("devPassword")
  val driverClass   = properties.getProperty("gpDriverClass")
```

I am submitting the jar file in the following way:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster --driver-memory 40g --driver-cores 3 --executor-memory 40g --executor-cores 20 --num-executors 5  --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties --jars /home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --class com.partition.source.YearPartition splinter_2.11-0.1.jar  --keytab /home/usrname/usrname.keytab --principal usrname@DEV.COM --name Splinter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

The job fails with the following error message:

```
client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.230.137.190
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1537545547309
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ip:port/proxy/application_123456789_76/
     user: fdlhdpetl
18/09/21 15:59:38 INFO Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://dev/user/usrname/.sparkStaging/application_123456789_76
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_123456789_76 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
18/09/21 15:59:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/09/21 15:59:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-59934097-dfe9-4ad2-a66a-ff93d42cf838
```

My dependencies in the build.sbt file:

```
name := "Splinter"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11" % "provided",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3"
)

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
```

Code used to read the table on postgres:

```
def prepareFinalDF(splitColumns:List[String], textList: ListBuffer[String], allColumns:String, dataMapper:Map[String, String], partition_columns:Array[String], spark:SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val execQuery = s"select ${allColumns}, 0 as ${flagCol} from schema.tablename where period_year='2017'"
  val yearDF    = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl).option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2017").option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword).option("numPartitions",20).load()
  val totalCols:List[String] = splitColumns ++ textList
  val cdt                    = new ChangeDataTypes(totalCols, dataMapper)
  hiveDataTypes              = cdt.gpDetails()
  prepareHiveTableSchema(hiveDataTypes, partition_columns)
  val allColsOrdered         = yearDF.columns.diff(partition_columns) ++ partition_columns
  val allCols                = allColsOrdered.map(colname => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(colname))
  val resultDF               = yearDF.select(allCols:_*)
  val stringColumns          = resultDF.schema.fields.filter(x => x.dataType == StringType).map(s => s.name)
  val finalDF                = stringColumns.foldLeft(resultDF) {
    (tempDF, colName) => tempDF.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col(colName), "[\r\n]+", " "), "[\t]+"," "))
  }
  finalDF
}
```

execQuery contains: `select * from schema.tablename where period_year=2017`

```
val dataDF = prepareFinalDF(splitColumns, textList, allColumns, dataMapper, partition_columns, spark)
dataDF.createOrReplaceTempView("preparedDF")
spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true")
spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE default.xx_gl_forecast PARTITION(${prtn_String_columns}) select * from preparedDF")
```

I checked the jar mentioned in the spark-submit and it is present in the dir given but it still fails when submitted.
Could anyone tell me what is the mistake I am doing here ? Is there any particular order to be followed while giving parameters in spark-submit ?

Comment: The "No suitable driver" exception message normally includes the JDBC url that was tried. Can you provide the full stacktrace of that exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JDBC driver for postgres has to be in the classpath not only of the spark driver but also in the executors. There are 3 ways to do it:

1. you build a fat jar that includes the driver. This means adding `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"` to your projects' `libraryDependencies`.
2. you tell spark to download the dependency from maven. In your case, add `--packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4` to your spark-submit (instead of --driver-class-path).
3. use `--jars` followed with the path to the drivers' jar. This will add the driver to both the driver's and executors' classpaths.

Comment: SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4 --jars /home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar  --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster --driver-memory 40g --driver-cores 3 --executor-memory 40g --executor-cores 20 --num-executors 5  --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties --class com.partition.source.YearPartition splinter_2.11-0.1.jar  --keytab /home/usrname/usrname.keytab --principal usrname@DEV.COM --name Splinter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar

Comment: I ran it in the above manner. In the logs I see the jar getting downloaded. But I still face the same exception.

Comment: can you post the code where you read from jdbc ?  the part like `spark.read.jdbc(...)`. You need `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` to load the driver, like mentioned here https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Comment: Added the part of code in the question which reads the table.

Comment: ok.. if the library is there, there may be an issue with the database URL. One thing I'd check is if the properties are read correctly, maybe add some logging to make sure the URL is read correctly from the property file.

Comment: Yes. The database URL had a mistake. Sorted it and it is not giving the same exception anymore.